# PHP issue with dropdown menu + image slider on WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Website: (hidden)

Slider has stopped working, and drop down menus too. Not sure why?
Would appreciate some direction on this one. Thank you.

Comment: Try clearing cache and deactivate JS compression in Autoptimize plugin settings

Comment: Legend. That worked. Thank you. Any ideas why Autoptimize was causing issues? It happened with our chat box too.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: For better views of next questions..- go throug Stack Overflow! Your question lacks information to get any help from [so] users. Please take the [tour], and read through the [help], learn  [ask] a good question? to maximize your chance to get answer to your questions. If you run into a specific problem and if you're stuck, send a description of the problem, including a [mcve] and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing cache and deactivate JS compression in **Autoptimize** plugin settings.
As the JS compression is making the jQuery as undefined as I can see in console